# $lookup in MongoDB Provides Unexpected Data Structure Result

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I am trying to understand why a `$lookup` I'm using in my MongoDB aggregation is producing the result it is.

First off, my initial data looks like this:

```
"subscriptions": [
    {
        "agency": "3dg2672f145d0598be095634", // This is an ObjectId
        "memberType": "primary"
    }
]
```

Now, what I want to do is a simple `$lookup`, pulling in the related data for the `ObjectId` that's currently being populated as the value to the "agency" field.

What I tried doing was a `$lookup` like this:

```
{
    "from" : "agencies",
    "localField" : "subscriptions.0.agency",
    "foreignField" : "_id",
    "as" : "subscriptions.0.agency"
}
```

So, basically what I want to do is go get that info related to that `ObjectId` ref, and populate it right here, in place of where the `ObjectId` currently resides.

What I'd expect as a result is something like this:

```
"subscriptions": [
    {
        "agency": [
          { 
            _id: <id-value>,
            name: <name-value>,
            address: <address-value>
          }
        ],
        "memberType": "primary"
    }
]
```

Instead, I end up with this (with my "memberType" prop now nowhere to be found):

```
"subscriptions" : {
    "0" : {
        "agency" : [ <agency-data> ]
    }
}
```

Why is this the result of the `$lookup`, and how can I get the data structure I'm looking for here?

To clarify further, in the docs they mention using an `$unwind` BEFORE the `$lookup` when it's an array field. But in this case, the actual local field being targeted and replaced by the `$lookup` is NOT an array, but it is within an array. So I'm not clear on what the problem is.

Comment: You can use `populate()` method too. Or you are stick to `$lookup`?

Comment: I want to know why this `$lookup` is doing this. And because this is actually a mongo view, not a collection, I'm not sure one can use populate() actually.

Comment: you need to `$unwind` your subscription

Comment: Thanks, but can you help me understand why - since the targeted local field is not an array? And in this case, $unwinding first would give me a document for every subscription -- which is not what I want. So how would I resolve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) to match your "localField" with to the "foreignField" and then [`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) to rollback again to the array

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { "$unwind": "$subsciption" },
  { "$lookup": {
    "from": Agency.collection.name,
    "localField": "subsciption.agency",
    "foreignField": "_id",
    "as": "subsciption.agency"
  }},
  { "$group": {
    "_id": "$_id",
    "memberType": { "$first": "$memberType" },
    "subsciption": { "$push": "$subsciption" },
  }}
])
```

Comment: Thanks. This was the key -- using $group along with $push to maintain subscriptions as an array.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, what OP is looking for is to transform data in desired format after looking up into another collection. Assuming there are two collections `C1` and `C2` where `C1` contains document

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5b50b8ebfd2b5637081105c6"), "subscriptions" : [ { "agency" : "3dg", "memberyType" : "primary" } ] }
```

and `C2` contains

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5b50b984fd2b5637081105c8"), "agency" : "3dg", "name" : "ABC", "address" : "1 some street" }
```

if following query is executed against database

```
db.C1.aggregate([
    {$unwind: "$subscriptions"}, 
    {
        $lookup: {
            from: "C2", 
            localField: "subscriptions.agency", 
            foreignField: "agency", 
            as: "subscriptions.agency"
        }
    }
])
```

We get result

```
{
    "_id": ObjectId("5b50b8ebfd2b5637081105c6"),
    "subscriptions": {
        "agency": [{
            "_id": ObjectId("5b50b984fd2b5637081105c8"),
            "agency": "3dg",
            "name": "ABC",
            "address": "1 some street"
        }],
        "memberyType": "primary"
    }
}
```

which is pretty close to what OP is looking forward.

> Note: there may be some edge cases but with minor tweaks, this solution should work